# Where do I find really fast internet access in Auckland, New Zealand?

Tags: internet, new-zealand, auckland

I have a ton of data to upload to my dropbox for backup purposes and the wifi at my hotel is just too slow.

How would I go about finding access to really fast internet in Auckland?  I have been to a couple of coffee shops , but they have a really slow upload as well.

Perhaps there is a library or a university that would allow guest access?

Comment: Sending any data back to the US, you will hit the limit of bandwidth delay product. Essentially you will only be able to use a fraction of the bandwidth, which decreases with the increase of latency.

Comment: Interesting.  What would you expect the fraction would be?

Comment: See addition at top of my answer.

Comment: The [university library](http://www.library.auckland.ac.nz/services/it-essentials/internet-and-wireless/wireless-access) does have an open WiFi network, however you can only access university websites. Not much of use for you unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks @BartArondson , I noticed that on the website. Maybe I should enroll? :)

Comment: If you know a student from [any of these countries](https://www.eduroam.org/index.php?p=where) you can ask if you could use their credentials to login on the `eduroam` network.

Comment: How big is "ton of data"? The city library has a daily traffic limit of 200MB per device as far as i know. It wont be fast, but you can read books while you wait :)

Comment: 150 GB of data.  It is a backup of an iPhoto library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realised what the correct answer is - a bit slow before.
I'm in Auckland, NZ. 
If still of use please contact me (see profile page).

- Place data on a USB memory stick.
- Trust me :-)
- Give me memory stick and upload details.

It will not be vastly fast, but I can set it to chug along as a background task on std ADSL throttled to a rate that does not annoy my game playing son too much. From your point of view it will be "as good as done" once you give me the data, so very fast.

---

The recently introduced VDSL is probably fast enough for you.
Actually claims to be faster than fibre best case.
Reality varies.
Up to 70 Mbps down and 10 Mbps up (!!!)
Finding someone with it is probably a matter of asking.

Telecom -> XTRA - > Spark call it "Ultra VDSL"
Here is the [Spark VDSL page](http://www.spark.co.nz/shop/internet/ultravdsl/) complete with a "check your address" box.

And

[BigPipe](https://www.bigpipe.co.nz/?gclid=Cj0KEQjw1s-gBRCKwOKQ1sWonvsBEiQA8qALFWkubNEH6Se1ps5j7Hs0yfEaLhpO-c7MYpq87gSKeoIaAlIn8P8HAQ#/home)

[Vodafone](http://www.vodafone.co.nz/vdsl/)

[Xtreme](http://www.xtreme.net.nz/connections/vdsl.php)

[Orcon](http://www.orcon.net.nz/external/genius/combined.php?techcat=ufb&banner=ufb&phone-rewrite=0800%2013%2066%2067&gclid=Cj0KEQjw1s-gBRCKwOKQ1sWonvsBEiQA8qALFUs98Vfn-xMNxyLgMdreSXbIrMtlccEUCHNDgt8VcbQaAtwz8P8HAQ)

---

[Spark is faster](http://www.nbr.co.nz/article/raw-data-truenet-august-2014-broadband-report-bigpipe-debut-outperforms-other-isp)

Comment: Given that this is on Travel.SE and the asker talks about a hotel, I don't think he's looking for home installation, but rather somewhere he can go to use a fast connection for a couple of hours.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question to further clarify that I am traveling staying at hotels and looking for a temporary place to move a large amount of data quickly.

Comment: I was somewhat appalled at Anonymous's suggested edits. Rejected by reviewers I'm pleased to say. Comparing his given reason with his edits makes him sound like he works for another ISP. If anyone wishes to make such extreme changes I'd hope they'd flag them in a comment 1st for discussion. And not have an anomalous name :-).

Answer (score 2):

My latest technique is to get any connection, and then use [Instabridge](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instabridge.android&hl=en) - a free app for Android, that does two very important things:

1. Shows where open wifi is (including password-protected ones which have been crowdsourced - e.g. a kind soul has added his home wifi to the list). This is displayed on a map.
2. For most of the access points shown, a tested speed for the connection is displayed as well. This quickly shows you at a glance where the fast wifi connections are.

Looking at it from here, it looks like there's a faster connection on Karangahape Road, and a community-provided one just west of Albert Park, both running around 6Mbps.

Comment: That is very cool.  And a great idea.  Too bad I don't have an android device.

Comment: @digidigo if a friend has one, it's a free app and they can send you a screenshot.